# insert binary(16) with executemany

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I store md5 hashes as binary(16) in a MSSQL Database. I need to insert several thousand values with pymssql, which is very slow if I insert the values one by one with `cursor.execute()` instead of `cursor.executemany()`.
But the problem is, that i cannot insert binary data, because executemany takes my list of md5 hashes and treat it as a string...

my insert line looks like this:

```
# generated from hashlib.md5('somestring').hexdigest()
md5list = ['9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6', 'e4d909c290d0fb1ca068ffaddf22cbd0']
# query should look like this: insert into hashes (md5) values (0x9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6)
cursor.executemany("insert into hashes (md5) values (0x%s)", md5list) 
# now we have a query like: insert into hashes (md5) values (0x'9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6')
```

is there a way to insert the hashes with executemany?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query parameter for [`Cursor.executemany`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany) should sequence of sequences.

Use `int(.., 16) to convert hexadecimal string to int.

```
>>> int('9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6', 16)
210103647840849757586127012022035159510L
>>> hex(int('9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6', 16))
'0x9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6L'
```

How about using list comprehension?

```
md5list = ['9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6',
           'e4d909c290d0fb1ca068ffaddf22cbd0']
params = [[int(h, 16)] for h in md5list]
cursor.executemany("insert into hashes (md5) values (%s)", params)
```

Comment: the problem is not the 0x but that pymssql assumes that this is a string type and adds the '' to it. when i try to insert '0x...' it simply does not work because mssql dont want a string there...

Comment: okay sorry, i edited your answer but that was also wrong... you cannot use the %x in pymssql and %s will always put it into ' '. :( and strings doesnt work with mssql

Comment: @reox, How about `%d`?

Comment: decimal does not work either on mssql... if i do a convert(binary(16), <decimal representation of md5>) i get a different value...

Comment: @reox, How about `params = [[binascii.unhexlify(h)] for h in md5list]` with `%s` formatting ? (You need to import [`binascii` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html))

Comment: okay this is so weird, now it works just fine with %s... thanks!

Comment: @reox, Do you mean `binascii.unhexlify` work for you?